# set cookies for a popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

Hello Sir/Friends i want to set cookies for a popup div, i am not a professional java or jquery coder but i have little knowledge about it.. so please help to setting up cookies for a popup div and also if you can please tell me how can i set days for it.. 
thanks in advance.. the code is below which is i am using for it..

```
<style>
#exepopup {
    background-color: white;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 10px solid #446c95;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    /* for Safari */
    background-clip: padding-box;
    /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 420px;
    height: 300;
    overflow: auto;
    left:50% !important;
    margin-left:-220px;
    margin-top:10%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#exepopup span {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
#exepopup h1 {
    background: #446c95 url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wbOyGFuANTQ/UVF1F4ouC4I/AAAAAAAABiA/RX4jNlICbjM/s1600/aktechz-fb-lock.png) 98% 30% no-repeat;
    border: 0px solid #3b5998 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
    font-family: arial !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.exepopupdata {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    height: 275px !important;
    padding: 1px !important;
    background: #fff !important;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ddd;
    overflow: show !important;
}
#exepopupfooter {
    text-align: right;
    font-size:12px;
    background: #F2F2F2 !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
#exepopupfooter p {
    text-align: right;
    font-size:12px;
}
#exepopupclose {
    float: right;
    background-color: #446c95 !important;
    border: 0px solid #ccc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    padding: 5px 35px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    font-family: arial !important;
    outline: none !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}  
</style>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        function exepopupfunc() {
            var sec = 60
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                $( & quot;#exepopupfooter span & quot;).text(sec--);
                if (sec == 0) {
                    $( & quot;#exepopup & quot;).fadeOut( & quot; slow & quot;);
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }, 1000);
            var exepopupwindow = jQuery(window).height();
            var exepopupdiv = jQuery( & quot;#exepopup & quot;).height();
            var exepopuptop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 50;
            jQuery( & quot;#exepopup & quot;).css({ & quot;
                top & quot;: exepopuptop
            });
        }
        jQuery(window).fadeIn(exepopupfunc).resize(exepopupfunc)
        //alert(jQuery.cookie(&#39;sreqshown&#39;));
        //var exepopupww = jQuery(window).width();
        //var exepopupwww = jQuery(&quot;#exepopup&quot;).width();
        //var exepopupleft = (exepopupww-exepopupwww)/2;
        var exepopupleft = 500;
        //var exepopupwindow = jQuery(window).height();
        //var exepopupdiv = jQuery(&quot;#exepopup&quot;).height();
        //var exepopuptop = (jQuery(window).scrollTop()+exepopupwindow-exepopupdiv) / 2;
        jQuery( & quot;#exepopup & quot;).animate({
            opacity: & quot;
            1 & quot;, left: & quot;
            0 & quot;, left: exepopupleft
        }, 0).show();
        jQuery( & quot;#exepopupclose & quot;).click(function() {
            jQuery( & quot;#exepopup & quot;).animate({
                opacity: & quot;
                0 & quot;, left: & quot; - 5000000 & quot;
            }, 1000).show();
        });
    });

    //setting cookies for popup window

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
        if (!readCookie('hide')) {
            $('#exepopup').show();
        }

        // Add the event that closes the popup and sets the cookie that tells us to
        // not show it again until one day has passed.
        $('#exepopupclose').click(function() {
            $('#exepopup').hide();
            createCookie('hide', true, 1)
            return false;
        });

    });

    // ---
    // And some generic cookie logic
    // ---
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        } else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name, "", -1);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a function that accepts 3 arguments, `name, value, days`:

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
```

You are calling this function here:

```
 createCookie('hide', true, 1)
```

This is creating a cookie named `hide` with a value of `true` that will last for `1 day`.

Change `1` to whatever you want in order to establish how many days the cookie will last.

Comment: ok thanks for helping about setting days.. but the cookies is not working in the code above...

Comment: @MyBloggerTricks Make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a minimal test case. Include only the necessary code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4sw4yva3/.. here is the jsfiddle link.. when i remove setting cookies code the popup is working fine..

Comment: @MyBloggerTricks Your code does not work in the jsFiddle. Please inspect the console and resolve the errors that it shows you. That should always be the first thing you do.

Comment: hello sir sory for inconvenience.. Please check it now..http://jsfiddle.net/4sw4yva3/3/ once again i explain my problem.. when i add cookies code in my script the close button is also hide and if cookies code is removed from script popup working fine with close button..

Comment: @MyBloggerTricks The code works fine, the problem is `jQuery("#exepopup").animate({
        opacity: "1",
        left: "0",
        left: exepopupleft
    }, 0).show()` always runs and forces it to `.show().`

Comment: Sir can you please make working jsfiddle, so then it will will be usefull for me.. thanks 7n advance..